# Capture vararg arguments with MockK?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

You can [mock](https://mockk.io/#varargs) a vararg method in MockK:

```kotlin
interface ClsWithManyMany {
    fun manyMany(vararg x: Any): Int
}

val obj = mockk<ClsWithManyMany>()
every { obj.manyMany(*anyVararg()) } returns 2
println(obj.manyMany("testing", "testing")) // 2
```

How can I capture the values passed to that method? This doesn't work (and neither does capturing a `mutableListOf<Array<Any>>()`):

```kotlin
val captured = slot<Array<Any>>()
every { obj.manyMany(*capture(captured)) } answers {
    println ("arguments: ${captured.captured}")
    2
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do the following:

```kotlin
val captured = mutableListOf<Any?>()
every { obj.manyMany(*varargAllNullable { captured.add(it) }) } answers {
    println ("arguments: $captured")
    captured.clear()
    2
}
```

[This issue](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/432) is open to allow for a less hacky way to do this.